# Firebase v8 Typescript definition import for User

Tags: typescript, firebase

With previous version of Firebase I use to import the Typescript definition of the `User` as following:

```
import {User} from 'firebase';
```

Following the introduction of **v8** this import does not work anymore:

> Module '"../../../../node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'User'. Did you mean to use 'import User from "../../../../node_modules/firebase"' instead?

The [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) points the fact that the CJS bundles was dropped, nevertheless, does not mention how this import should now be resolved.

Any help appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20):

For V9.0.0(Web version 9 (modular), this can be done by

```
// make alias for greater readability
import { User as FirebaseUser } from "firebase/auth";
```

Then you can use it by:

```
// here direct use the type inside a hooks 
const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseUser | null>(null)
```

Answer (score 16):

You can say this instead:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
const user: firebase.User = ...
```

Or if you want to abbreviate it:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
type User = firebase.User
const user: User = ...
```

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you for your answer. That was my guess too but it leads to a `TS2694: Namespace '"...node_modules/firebase/index"' has no exported member 'User'.` error.

Comment: I don't get that error at all.  I actually tried the code you see here.

Comment: Weird . Meanwhile I think I found a solution. I am able to import the definition as following: `import {User} from '@firebase/auth-types';`

Answer (score 13):

I was able to solve my issue while importing the `User` with thee Firebase JS SDK v8.0.0 as following:

```
import {User} from '@firebase/auth-types';
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/auth-types) suggests that you're not supposed to use it directly.  This is something that could break in the future.

Comment: Good to know. Note that I don't reference the lib explicitly, it comes together with the officially supported package.

Comment: By importing from it directly, that is considered direct use. The main modules could change at any time and remove or change its "private" dependencies like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing firebase and then accessing User with `firebase.User` ?
It's obviously way more chunky but worked for me.

Edit:
I was also having issues with conflicting imports previously - where I had a file called firebase.ts that was causing my app to zoink out. Just mentioning it in case you *by chance* have something similar

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed I gave it a try but it did not work out, kind of strange.

Comment: Ahh :/ And you're using firebase 8.0 right? Do you mind pasting the code you tried for the above?

Comment: Yes Firebase v8 and I did exactly what you suggested (`import firebase from '@firebase/app';` + `const user: firebase.User;`).

Comment: thanks for the edit, did not find any such file but yes that's a valid point, maybe/probably something weird in my project. If interested its in https://github.com/deckgo/deckdeckgo/ in the app "studio". Can give  a try  for example in `auth.service.tsx`.

Comment: I just started trying to update my Angular 9 app to Angular 11 and I ran into this same problem and found this page. This is what I did. I imported firebase only "import 'firebase'" then to get access to the 'User'  interface I used 'firebase.default.User' to get access to the interface.

Comment: I noticed that I was getting a console warning because of the way that I was doing it above. That warning went away when I did it another way. 

"import firebase from 'firebase/app';" then "firebase.User"  to refer to the User interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular you can import AngularFire:

```js
import { User } from '@angular/fire/auth';

export class HomeToolbarService {
  user: User;
}
```

To do this I had to go into `tsconfig.json` and add this:

```js
"compilerOptions": {
  "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another alternative to `import`ing `firebase` is to add the firebase types in an `index.d.ts` file:

```
/// <reference types="firebase" />

type Firebase = typeof firebase.default

type FirebaseApp = firebase.default.app.App

type FirebaseUser = firebase.default.User
```

Note: I had to do `firebase.default` instead of `firebase` because I am using triple slash directives `/// <reference types="..." />`

You can omit `.default` by just importing firebase in the `index.d.ts` file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"

type Firebase = typeof firebase

type FirebaseApp = firebase.app.App

type FirebaseUser = firebase.User
```

Answer (score 0):

For React Native with Typescript, from [React Native Firebase Docs](https://rnfirebase.io/typescript)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import auth, { FirebaseAuthTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged(userState => {
      setUser(userState);

      if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could be more descriptive in your answer